# Use of super() function in python 3.6

Tags: python, super

When I try:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = False

    def check_flag(self):
        if self.flag: return True
        else: return False

    def create(self):
        b = B()
        b.foobar()

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 0

    def foobar(self):
        while super().check_flag() == False:
         `print("Works"`)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    a.create()
```

I get the error:
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'flag'

I basically want an object B to call a function from its specific parent object A. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I should specify, That the parent object's flag may be changed by a different function, so the child object needs to constantly check what that flag's status is. I may try to use threads but I'm sure there's a simpler way using super().

Comment: You have to call the `A` constructor from `B`.

Comment: You shouldn't call `super().check_flag()` anyway, you should call `self.check_flag()`.

Comment: Please check the duplicate marked question, the first answer shows how to initialize parent class constructor (`__init__`).